# Google Apps Script cUrl request

Tags: curl, google-apps-script

I am pretty new to `Google Apps Script`. I am trying to create a script to pull data from a public API.

The API documenation indicates that the information can be accessed like this:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET 
--header "X-PW-AccessToken:<TOKEN>" \
--header "X-PW-Application:developer_api" \
--header "X-PW-UserEmail:<USER_EMAIL_ADDRESS>" \
https://api.prosperworks.com/developer_api/v1/leads/2
```

I have this function setup in `Apps Script`:

```
function myFunction() {
  var url = "https://api.prosperworks.com/developer_api/v1/leads/2";
  var headers = {
             "contentType": "application/json",
             "headers":{"X-PW-AccessToken": "<TOKEN>",
                        "X-PW-Application": "developer_api",
                        "X-PW-UserEmail": "<USER_EMAIL_ADDRESS>"}
             };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, headers);
  var text = response.getResponseCode();
  Logger.log(text);
}
```

When I run the code, the response appears to be empty but `text` is `200`.

[image]

I am able to make a call in `Postman` and get the expected `JSON` object.

What am I doing wrong in `Apps Script`? How do I access the `JSON` object?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Without having code to test, it is hard to know for sure, but it looks like you just need to parse your `JSON`

Try adding:

```
var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
```

Comment: That was it! Thanks. Now, I just have to write the rest of the code. :)

Comment: alternative to UrlFetchApp? customer: "connection to authorization server is established using Mutual SSL...only accepts connection setup via TLS 1.2 or higher". Eric Koleda (https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2/issues/168#issuecomment-461441855):
"..Apps Script's `UrlFetchApp`..doesn't allow custom TLS certificates .. 
Without .. won't be able to support that OAuth2 flow. [more] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#missing_features "
i found: Please "Make call APIs possible under SSL client certificate protection"
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120461462